# OrganizationProfileManager - obsolete

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

> [Obsolete("This class is no longer supported."),
>   SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDem­and,
>   ObjectModel=true), SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
>   ObjectModel=true)]
>       public class OrganizationProfileManager : ProfileManagerBase

What should I use insted?

Answer (score 1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-HA102892827.aspx#_Toc349821242

You can use it in SharePoint 2013, but the next major release, the code will not work.